# How do i fade out the original picture and then fade in different picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So This is My Javascript codes and basically what this does is it changes a picture to another picture depending on what color the user wants or which image(Panda or Dj) the user wants.

What do i add to make the old picture fade out and the new picture fade in?

my html can call switch the images perfectly fine, i just have no idea how to add the cool effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function O(obj)
    {
        if (typeof obj == 'object') 
            return obj;
        else 
            return document.getElementById(obj) 
    }

    var head = "Dj"
    var headcolor = "pink"


        function headpink(){headcolor = "pink"; changehead();}
        function headblue(){headcolor = "blue"; changehead();}
        function headdefault(){headcolor = "default"; changehead();}
        function headred(){headcolor = "red"; changehead();}


        function DjHead(){head = "Dj"; changehead();}
        function PandaHead(){head = "Panda"; changehead();}


    function changehead()
        {
        if (head == "Dj")
            {
                if(headcolor == "pink"){headImagePath = 'head/DjPink.png';}
                if(headcolor == "blue"){headImagePath = 'head/DjBlue.png';}
                if(headcolor == "red"){headImagePath = 'head/DjRed.png';}
                if(headcolor == "default"){headImagePath = 'head/DjDefault.png';}
            }
        if (head == "Panda")
            {
                if(headcolor == "pink"){headImagePath = 'head/PandaPink.png';}
                if(headcolor == "blue"){headImagePath = 'head/PandaBlue.png';}
                if(headcolor == "red"){headImagePath = 'head/PandaRed.png';}
                if(headcolor == "default"){headImagePath = 'head/PandaDefault.png';}
            }

                O("head").src = headImagePath;
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: You should really think about using if/else if statement or switch case

Comment: Have you considered using CSS transitions?

Comment: im not familiar with css transitions but to my knowledge i can only fade in and out 2 alternating images with css. I'm not sure how to do so with a larger array of pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/); these function allows you to show/hide elements with an effect

Please instead of some similar if, consider to use `switch` statement.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Code (not tested):

```
function O(obj) {
    if (typeof obj == 'object') return obj;
    else return document.getElementById(obj)
}

var head = "Dj"
var headcolor = "pink"
var headImagePath;


    function headpink() {
        headcolor = "pink";
        changehead();
    }

    function headblue() {
        headcolor = "blue";
        changehead();
    }

    function headdefault() {
        headcolor = "default";
        changehead();
    }

    function headred() {
        headcolor = "red";
        changehead();
    }


    function DjHead() {
        head = "Dj";
        changehead();
    }

    function PandaHead() {
        head = "Panda";
        changehead();
    }


    function changehead() {
        switch (head) {
            case "Dj":
                switch (headcolor) {
                    case "pink":
                        headImagePath = 'head/DjPink.png';
                        break
                    case "blue":
                        headImagePath = 'head/DjBlue.png';
                        break
                    case "red":
                        headImagePath = 'head/DjRed.png';
                        break
                    case "default":
                        headImagePath = 'head/DjDefault.png';
                        break
                }
                break;
            case "Panda":
                switch (headcolor) {
                    case "pink":
                        headImagePath = 'head/PandaPink.png';
                        break
                    case "blue":
                        headImagePath = 'head/PandaBlue.png';
                        break
                    case "red":
                        headImagePath = 'head/PandaRed.png';
                        break
                    case "default":
                        headImagePath = 'head/PandaDefault.png';
                        break
                }
                break
        }

        $(O("head")).fadeOut(700, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', headImagePath).fadeIn(700);
        });

    }
```

Comment: all your head* functions should be refactorized to use only one function IMHO

Comment: Thanks for helping, but there's one problem if you could still help me with. It's that the image fades off, WHICH IS GREAT, but the new image doesn't fade in. Suddenly the space just goes blank.

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating yourself a lot here and not using jQuery.

Why not just store the options in an object like this:

```
var options = {
  head: ['Panda', 'Default']
};
```

Then you can just do:

```
var $head = $('#head');

var getHeadImage = function(){
  return '/head/' + options.head.join('') + '.png';
};

$head.fadeOut('slow', function(){
  $head.attr('src', getHeadImage).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the filenames in an array, and then use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/)
 to fade in and out?